# Knitr/Pandoc conversion to PDF fails with "could not find image" error

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

I am using RStudio on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. I've rendered PDFs in the past with no problems. The document loads in a few .rda files in one code chunk and then graphs them with ggplot in the rest of the code chunks. When I run my RMD file, it gets all the way to the end and then gives the following error:

```
[pandoc warning] Could not find image `new_document_files/figure-latex/5/17%20run%20#1%20results-1.pdf', skipping...
```

And so on for all the ggplot outputs for each of my code chunks. Note that I am not trying to insert any images or anything like that. Most of the questions I was able to find that gave a similar error were due to absolute paths when trying to insert a PNG file. This isn't the case here. It looks like the temporary files generated for each plot are not being stitched together into the PDF. My RMD file is in the same directory as all the .rda files.

The PDF does save however. Interestingly, the plot from the first code chunk shows up but the rest, which are related to the errors, are just empty pages (with my markdown headers on each page but no plots).

Additionally, I can run each individual code chunk within RStudio and see the plots with no problem. The issue seems to only occur at the end.

Here is the skeleton of my RMD file. I'll update with a reproducible example when I have access to a computer with RMarkdown/Knitr.

````
---
title: "Datasets (5/16, 5/17, 5/18)"
author: "XXX"
date: "May 18, 2018"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

Elastic net model fit for data. Data sets are from dates 5/16, 5/17, and 5/18.

```{r Load packages, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
### Packages
```

```{r Load functions, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
### Functions
```

```{r Load data, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
### Load data sets
```

```{r 5/16 results, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
### Plot 1
```

\pagebreak

```{r 5/17 run #1 results, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
### Plot 2
```

\pagebreak

```{r 5/17 run #2 results, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
### Plot 3
```

\pagebreak

```{r 5/18 run #1 results, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
### Plot 4
```

\pagebreak

```{r 5/18 run #2 results, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
### Plot 5
```
````

Comment: There's nothing reproducible here, but the filename `17%20run%20#1%20results-1.pdf` looks like it has spaces (converted to %20) in it, which is always a bad idea in LaTeX.  Maybe it came from your chunk name, maybe from a `fig.path` setting.

Comment: @user2554330 I don't have access to my files at the moment so I can't try it out but most likely this is the reason. Probably related to [this](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/544) Knitr issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `knitr` docs at https://yihui.name/knitr/options/ say:

> Avoid spaces and periods . in chunk labels and directory names; if your output is a TeX document, these characters can cause troubles (in general it is recommended to use alphabetic characters with words separated by - or _ and avoid other characters),

So names like `Load packages` are bad because of the space, and `5/17 run #1 results` has problems from the space, `#` and `/` characters.  The quote above doesn't mention including digits, but I've never had a problem with those.

So I'd suggest names like `Load_packages`, `May-17-run-1-results`.